Highlighting the nested tags
Different colors of the beginning and end tags:

How do I make such tag nesting highlighting in WebStorm? (the beginning and end of the tags have different colors at different nesting levels)
I tried to set this up in the settings, but I didn't find the right items.

If I'm getting this all correctly... 1) The enable/disable switch: Settings/Preferences | Editor | General | Appearance | Enable HTML/XML tag tree highlighting 2) The colors: Settings/Preferences | Editor | Color Scheme | HTML | Tag tree (level 1) and so on (1 to 6, can be more, depending on your settings) 3) The color will not be that intense (it will be lighter), that is controlled by Opacity value from #1. How it looks -- https://imgur.com/kthrfO9

If that is different to what you want... then most likely it will be some plugin, for example Rainbow Brackets or similar to that. Or maybe it's a feature of some other type of plugin (e.g. Material Theme UI)

You're talking about highlighting the background of the entire tag name, and I'm talking about highlighting the font of the characters <>

In such a case it must be a plugin. I'd suggest to search for "brackets" or "nested" and go through the list.
